# $a<x+y \Rightarrow \exists x_0,y_0$ such that $a = x_0+y_0$ and $x_0<x, y_0<y$

Tags: real-analysis, field-theory

Suppose $S$ is an ordered field and $a, x, y\in S$ area such that $ a<x+y $. Does this implies that exist some $x_0$ and $y_0$ in $S$ such that $a = x_0+y_0$ with $x_0 < x$ and $y_0 < y$? That question arised when I was trying to prove $\sup(A+B) = \sup A + \sup B$.

Comment: The strict inequality is false. Consider $S=\{z\in\mathbb Z~:~z\leq 0\}$ and $a=-2$, $x=-1$ and $y=0$. You get $a<x+y$ but there is no $x_0,y_0\in S$ such that $a=x_0+y_0$ with $x_0<x$ and $y_0<y$. But do you really need the strict inequality?

Comment: @bof sorry, it's an ordered field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $a\lt x+y$ then $a=x+y-d$ for some $d\gt0,$ namely $d=x+y-a.$ Then $$a=x+y-d=\left(x-\frac d2\right)+\left(y-\frac d2\right)=x_0+y_0$$ where $x_0=x-\frac d2\lt x$ and $y_0=y-\frac d2\lt y.$